# Why does sqlite database browser freeze instead of give an error?

Tags: sqlite

When using the SQLite Database Browser if I don't use the right syntax the whole program freezes instead of provides an error message.  Is anyone else running into this and if so is there some way around this?  The only way around it is for me to force quit the whole application and start over again.

Otherwise is there a better free sqlite query browser I could use for simple queries?

Thanks.

Comment: Have you seen http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1507506/what-are-good-open-source-gui-sqlite-database-managers ?

Comment: That has some good stuff on it.  But I still would like to know why the one I'm using freezes...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Ok, the assumed answer is that the SqLite Database Browser sucks and it not fully operational.  I will try some of the other free sqlite browsers and press my luck.